# Why did my miner stop working?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

It is named "Miner". Other than that I'm not sure if its a IC2, BC3 or some other miner.

My Miner has hit bedrock, and will not retract. Why? I have removed the remaining pipes from the Miner unit and replaced the pipes with cobblestone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to also remove the Drill Unit or else the Miner will not start to retract.